# Radius of convergence of $\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}\frac{ k^{2 k + 5} \ln^{10} k \ln \ln k}{\left(k!\right)^2} x^k$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, power-series

I want to find the radius of convergence of

$$\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}\frac{ k^{2 k + 5} \ln^{10} k \ln \ln k}{\left(k!\right)^2} \,x^k$$

I know formulae 
$$R=\dfrac{1}{\displaystyle\limsup_{k\to\infty} \sqrt[k]{\left\lvert a_k\right\rvert}}.$$

For this power series 
$$R= \dfrac{1}{\limsup_{k\to\infty}{\displaystyle\sqrt[k]{\dfrac{ k^{2 k + 5} \ln^{10} k \ln \ln k}{\left(k!\right)^2}}}}.$$

But I don't know how calculate $\;\displaystyle\limsup_{k\to\infty} \sqrt[k]{\frac{ k^{2 k + 5} \ln^{10} k \ln \ln k}{\left(k!\right)^2}}$

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Could you explain $ln^{10} k$?

Comment: Then find it, if you want it...

Comment: HINT:  $(k!)^2\sim 2\pi\,k \,(k/e)^{2k}$

Comment: @Dr.MV, $\lim \sup_{k\to\infty} \sqrt[k]{\frac{ k^{2 k + 5} \ln^{10} k \ln \ln k}{(k!)^2}}$ = $\lim \sup_{k\to\infty} \sqrt[k]{\frac{e^{2 k} k^5 \ln^{10} k \ln \ln k}{2 \pi k }}$ = $e^2$.

Is it true?

Comment: $e^2$, not $2e$

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:**

[Stirling's Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation#Derivation) states

$$k! =\sqrt{2\pi k}\left(\frac ke\right)^k \left(1+O\left(\frac1k\right)\right)$$

Then,

$$\left(\frac{k^{2k+5}\,(\log k)^{10}\,\log (\log k)}{(k!)^2}\right)^{1/k}\sim e^2\,\left(\frac{k^{4}\,(\log k)^{10}\,\log (\log k)}{2\pi}\right)^{1/k}\to e^2$$

Comment: Who down voted this?  Would you care to comment as to why?

Comment: Cancelling the anonymous downvote via a +1.  Don't see a reason for it.

Comment: @shailesh Thank you!  Very much appreciated.  Happy Holidays! - Mark

Comment: Thanks. And best wishes from $2^{13}$ miles away.

Comment: @Shailesh Wow, $2^{13}$ miles ... now that is "out of this world" far! ;-)

Comment: GH, why was the "best vote" rescinded? Please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can.  Happy Holidays. - Mark

Answer (score 0):

We have $$\sqrt[k]{\frac{ k^{2 k + 5} \ln^{10} k \ln \ln k}{\left(k!\right)^2}} = \left(\frac {k^4 e^{2k} \log^{10} k \log \log k} {2 \pi} \left(1 + O \left(\frac {1} {k}\right)\right)\right)^{1/k} \to e^2,$$ so $$R = \frac {1} {e^2}.$$

Answer (score 0):

You can use 
$$ R=\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{a_k}{a_{k+1}}. $$
In fact,
\begin{eqnarray}
R&=&\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{ k^{2 k + 5} \ln^{10} k \ln \ln k}{\left(k!\right)^2}\frac{\left((k+1)!\right)^2}{ (k+1)^{2 (k+1) + 5} \ln^{10} (k+1) \ln \ln (k+1)}\\
&=&\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{k^{2 k + 5}}{(k+1)^{2 (k+1) + 5}}\bigg[\frac{\ln k}{\ln(k+1)}\bigg]^{10}\frac{\ln\ln k}{\ln\ln(k+1)}\bigg[\frac{(k+1)!}{k!}\bigg]^2\\
&=&\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{k^{2 k + 6}}{(k+1)^{2 (k+1) + 4}}\\
&=&\lim_{k\to\infty}\bigg(\frac{k}{k+1}\bigg)^{2k+6}\\
&=&\frac{1}{e^2}.
\end{eqnarray}